# Prevent Default behavior on links

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain why this code isn't preventing the default behavior on all the links in the html? I've tried just about every combination but still the links do not disable. I also would like to change the background color on the links when they are clicked

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

  <title>Goal8: Simple Library</title>

</head>
<html>

<body>

<div id="container">

  <h1>Goal8: Simple Library</h1>

  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a>
  <a href="http://fullsail.com">FullSail</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ryu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
(function(){
  var ahref= [];

  var links = function(){
    var urls = document.querySelectorAll("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
      var aLinks = urls[i].href;
      ahref.push(aLinks);

      urls[i].onclick = function(e){
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }

    }
    console.log(ahref);
    return ahref;

  }; links();

})();
```

Comment: you are testing this against which browser ?

Comment: I see no problem in this code? http://jsfiddle.net/kKCyc/. Running this on IE might cause some problem because `console.log()`, it will throw error before you execute `links();`.

Comment: IE<9? If so, your browser doesn't pass `e` when using `onEventname` property of an element.

Comment: Im running on google chrome

Comment: its working as it should now, thanks